# Call some function after $state.go will finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to call some function after transition? I mean after loading section. I tried with promise, but it called right after transition started.

```
$state.go('app.one.two').then(function(d){
    // do staff
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: you should thinnk of resolve option in state

Answer (score 5):

You need to look for stateChangeSuccess event. This event will be triggered on every stateChangeSuccess, hence, you have to place a check for your state in order to do some state specific work.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
    if(toState.name == 'app.one.two') {
       //Do something
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You could listen to the $state events

```
  // Check if a state change happened
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
    function onStateSuccess(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
      //stuff
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) you can define `onEnter` and `onExit` callbacks maybe that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

`$state.go` return the promise so you have to pass some element after redirection state and then you can add callback function

```
$state.go('app.one.two', {null:null}).then(function(d){
    // add functionality
});
```

Here I am passing null value with redirection state, if you have to pass any id or some data to next page then you can pass in `{}` as a object

Comment: I don't think this works... $state.go returns a resolved promise before the transition has actually completed